# Moving an HTML Image across an HTML Canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, draggable

I am trying to make all my images in my HTML canvas draggable by the click of a mouse. I have read/watched every question and tutorial I can find 3-4 times over now, and can not figure out why my code is not working.

I am able to make all my images appear in the canvas based off the click of a dropdown button menu, but I can't do anything with them once they are in there despite the coding to do so. Any help on what I am missing would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
<div class="dropdown">
              <button onclick="adultlist()" ondblclick="adultlist2()"   class="dropbtn">Adults</button>
              <div id="adults" class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href = "javascript:drawa1()">Adult 1</a> 
                  <a href = "javascript:drawa2()">Adult 2</a> 
                  <a href = "javascript:drawa3()">Adult 3</a> 
                  <a href = "javascript:drawa4()">Adult 4</a> 
                  <a href = "javascript:drawa5()">Adult 5</a> 
                  <a href = "javascript:drawa6()">Adult 6</a>
                  <a href = "javascript:drawa7()">Adult 7</a> 
                  <a href = "javascript:drawa8()">Adult 8</a> 
                  <a href = "javascript:drawa9()">Adult 9</a> 
                  <a href = "javascript:drawa10()">Adult 10</a>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <script>
        function adultlist() {
         document.getElementById("adults").classList.toggle("show");
         }
         window.onclick = function(adultlist) {
         if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
         var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
         var i;
         for (i = 10; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
         var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
         if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
         openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
               }
             }
           }
         }
              </script>


<div class="img_cont">
    <img id="adult1" width="100" height="290" src="SILHOUETTE PNG'S/silhouette_adult1.png" alt="Adult 1" class="hidden">
    <img id="adult2" width="145" height="290" src="SILHOUETTE PNG'S/silhouette_adult2.png" alt="Adult 2" class="hidden">
    <img id="adult3" width="135" height="290" src="SILHOUETTE PNG'S/silhouette_adult3.png" alt="Adult 3" class="hidden">
    <img id="adult4" width="110" height="290" src="SILHOUETTE PNG'S/silhouette_adult4.png" alt="Adult 4" class="hidden">
    <img id="adult5" width="136" height="290" src="SILHOUETTE PNG'S/silhouette_adult5.png" alt="Adult 5" class="hidden">
    <img id="adult6" width="142" height="290" src="SILHOUETTE PNG'S/silhouette_adult6.png" alt="Adult 6" class="hidden">
    <img id="adult7" width="117" height="290" src="SILHOUETTE PNG'S/silhouette_adult7.png" alt="Adult 7" class="hidden">
    <img id="adult8" width="109" height="290" src="SILHOUETTE PNG'S/silhouette_adult8.png" alt="Adult 8" class="hidden">                                                                                                              
    <img id="adult9" width="116" height="290" src="SILHOUETTE PNG'S/silhouette_adult9.png" alt="Adult 9" class="hidden"> 
    <img id="adult10" width="87" height="290" src="SILHOUETTE PNG'S/silhouette_adult10.png" alt="Adult 10" class="hidden">
    </div>


<canvas class="preview" id="canvas" width="345" height="350"> 
      Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <button class="clearbutton" onclick="clearcanvas1()">Clear</button>
<script>
    function clearcanvas1() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}   
    function drawa1() {
          var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
          var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");
          var img= new Image();
          a1_img = new Image();
          img.onload = function() {
          var img= document.getElementById("adult1");
              ctx.drawImage(a1_img, canvas.width/2,canvas.width/2); 
          }, 200);
      };
    document.getElementById("adult1").src="SILHOUETTE PNG'S/silhouette_adult1.png"
    const resetCanvas = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }

    let draggable = false;
    canvas.onmousedown = (e) => {
        //detect if the click was on the image;
        if(e.layerX <= (currentX + a1_img.width/2) &&
          e.layerX >= (currentX - a1_img.width/2) &&
          e.layerY <= (currentY + a1_img.height/2) &&
          e.layerY >= (currentY - a1_img.height/2)) {
          draggable = true;
        }
    }
    canvas.onmousemove = (e) => {
        if(draggable) {
            currentX = e.layerX
            currentY = e.layerY
        }
    }
    canvas.onmouseup = (e) => {
        draggable = false;
    }
    canvas.onmouseout = (e) => {
        draggable = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for the mouse move is this:

```
    canvas.onmousemove = (e) => {
        if(draggable) {
            currentX = e.layerX
            currentY = e.layerY
        }
    }
```

All you are doing there is setting a couple of variables...

- those variables are not used in the drawing of images
- no re-draw of the canvas is called with the mouse move

To "move" something in a canvas you have to clear the canvas and draw a new one with the object in the new position, I will suggest you start with something simpler then go with the many images option

---

One thing you can do to simplify all your code is to use a library that handles moving of images for you, one option is `fabric.js` see sample code below, you can see that image elements by default allow us to move them and resize them.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var image = document.getElementById('image');

var img = new fabric.Image(image, {left: 10, top: 50});
canvas.setActiveObject(img);
canvas.add(img);
```

```css
#image {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas width="400" height="300" id="canvas"></canvas>
<img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png" id="image">
```

---

Here is a more complex example using multiple images

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var lastPos = {x: 10, y: 50}

function addImage(imageName, p) {
  var image = document.getElementById(imageName);
  var img = new fabric.Image(image, {left: p.x, top: p.y, width: 80, height: 80});
  canvas.setActiveObject(img);
  canvas.add(img);
}

function addFlag() {
  var selected = document.getElementById("flags").value
  addImage(selected, lastPos)
  lastPos = {x: lastPos.x + 20, y: lastPos.y + 10}
}
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>

<select name="flags" id="flags">
  <option value="image1">Flag Charlie</option>
  <option value="image2">Flag Lima</option>
  <option value="image3">Flag November</option>
</select>
<button onclick="addFlag()" >Add Flag</button>
<canvas width="400" height="300" id="canvas"></canvas>

<img id="image1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/ICS_Charlie.svg">
<img id="image2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/ICS_Lima.svg">
<img id="image3" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/ICS_November.svg">
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This made so much more sense and I have it working the way I need it to, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Taylor if this answers your question remember to flag is as such